# Looking to record time taken to click a link on a page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, time

I'm looking to set up an experiment to test 2 separate webpage layouts and find out which one allows users to scan the page and find information the quickest.

So in each layout there will be a link 'click me' with a unique ID. I will ask a group of users to view both layouts and click the link as soon as they see it.

I want to record how long it takes each user to click the link and record that time somewhere. So I'm thinking the solution might be a combination of jQuery/Ajax and PHP.

Anyone have any suggestions of stuff that's out there already or how this could be done, relatively easily? I'm a frontend designer rather than developer but have some jQuery knowledge.

Thanks in advance.
Steve

P.s - happy to use Wordpress or something off the shelf for this experiment.

Comment: Have a google for A-B testing. There are lots of sites which offer this service for you.

Comment: Had a quick look and it looks like event tracking and goals could be used but not sure how exactly. I know analytics record visits and duration but can it be used to determine what I am asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fairly simple, get the time in milliseconds when the page load, then again when the user clicks, and compare

```
var start = new Date();

$(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
         var stop = new Date();

         var elapsed = stop.getTime() - start.getTime();

    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zLu1a2c4/)

To store the times somewhere that you can access them and do stuff, you'll have to send the times to the serverside first.

```
$(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
         var stop = new Date();
         var elapsed = stop.getTime() - start.getTime();

         $.ajax({
             url  : 'script.php',
             data : {time : elapsed}
         });

    });
});
```

and on the server you'll get the times with

```
$_GET['time'];
```

then you'll have to figure out how and where to store them, I'd recommend setting up a database.

Comment: Seems to work quite nicely but how do I then submit that result to a database onclick?
P.s thanks for the image! At work and that popped up!

Comment: I've added a really simple ajax example, but how to set up PHP, a database, and to store the values in the database is somewhat involved. See how far you get, and when you have issues ask specific questions about the issues you're having, we don't really want to do your job for you, but we're here when you're stuck

Comment: Cool beans - found this which should do the trick for the next step: http://gordoncluster.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/how-to-insert-data-into-mysql-database-using-jquery-ajax-php/

Cheers